# Read data from GPS Uart

Tags: gps, nmea

I'm using a Mediatek MT3333 GPS receiver (baudrate: 115200 bpS), but all I'm getting is this:

```
b'$GNGGA,132002.448,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*5C\r\n'
b'$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E\r\n'
b'$GLGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*02\r\n'
b'$GPGSV,1,1,00*79\r\n'
b'$GLGSV,1,1,00*65\r\n'
b'$GNRMC,132002.448,V,,,,,0.00,0.00,100417,,,N*5A\r\n'
b'$GNVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*2C\r\n'
```

After some research I found that my receiver doesn't have a fix, any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What's the brand and model of the GPS antenna you are using?

Comment: You've taken it outdoors with a clear view of the southern sky, right?  Sometimes you have to send a command to enable the receiver on these.

Comment: @thewaywewere the GPS receive module has an internal antenna it has a built in low noise amplifier so i guess there is no need for an external antenna.

Comment: @Brad i haven't tried it outside however i left near the window runing all night and i got it to work but just for a few hours  now i'm getting  the same results as before

Comment: Can you EDIT your post to include some photo images of your GPS and its placement near the window? Also see my answer posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that the received signal strength is low so that your GPS receiver mode doesn't get a `GPS FIX`. It would be better to place the device outdoor to verify if there is a stable reception.

From the GPS sentences showed above, your Mediatek MT3333 GPS receiver output modified [NMEA 0183 Sentence](http://www.tronico.fi/OH6NT/docs/NMEA0183.pdf). All the standard sentence should started with `$GP` as the suffix and with format of `$GPaaa`, where `aaa` is alphabetic.

For instance,

- `b'$GNRMC,132002.448,V,,,,,0.00,0.00,100417,,,N*5A\r\n'` should be read as
- `$GPRMC,132002.448,V,,,,,0.00,0.00,100417,,,N*5A` if conforms to NMEA. This sentence tells that at `2017-04-10 12:30:02 (GMT)` got `no GPS fix` with speed at `0 knot` and course at `0 degree`.

If the output of your GPS receiver conforms NMEA, you can use some free software, such as [VisualGPS](http://www.visualgps.net/), to evaluation the GPS signal quality.

If possible, suggest to change the GPS antenna to external one, an active GPS antenna with 2-stage amplifier at around 28dBm gain, to improve the GPS signal reception in order to get a stable fix.

From the [datasheet of Mediatek MT3333](https://labs.mediatek.com/en/download/VT9qMakW), it did mention below for improving GPS signal reception:

> An external antenna and high gain external LNA connected to the
>   internal LNA in low-gain mode, which offers high linearity. In this
>   configuration, external LNA gain ranging from 15 to 20 dB is
>   recommended. The maximum total external RF front end gain including
>   active antenna and external LNA can be 43dB.

Hope this help.

Comment: @ahmed9207 If my answer helps, can you give me a vote up? And tick the answer if it helps to answer your question finally?

Comment: sorry for the late response, so after some testing i think you are right, when indoors the gps signal is not that great so it's a bit hard to get a stable fix

Comment: Any photo of the GPS antenna? Even a onboard one if not external?

Comment: sorry i don't have it  right now but i'll post a photo soon